# Add the image path in script to get the image from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Background** :

I need to get the image from path from below json file :

```
{
  "path" : " shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : ""   
  },
  "name" : "shape",
  "layers" : [
    {     
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {         
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {         
          "height" : 475,
          "layers" : [
            {

              "src" : "http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png",             
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {              
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],          
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],      
      "name" : "loveshape_17"
    }
  ]
}
```

I successfully did it with below code :

```
var maskedImageUrla = "";

    $.getJSON('test.json', function(json) {
        for (let layer of json.layers) {
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0) {
                for (let temp of layer.layers) {
                    if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers) {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src) maskedImageUrla = tl.src;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Requirement** :

In above json file if src is like this : `"src" : "oneheart.png"` [instead of full path] , than how to get the image ? becasue image exist in this path : `http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png`

Here is [Full script](https://pastebin.com/DrmuzEA3) & [json file](https://pastebin.com/pChkBaHV)

Comment: If the path is fixed, search of `/` and append the url if it is not found

Comment: @CerlinBoss Thanks for suggestion, means are you telling me to add full url in json file ? sorry, i have thousands of json files..... so i need to do with code.... as the path is same for all thousand json files...

Comment: You don't have to add path in json file. Just keep a variable with domain name like : var a = http://sitename.com/images/ and concat the name of file when creating the element like this : imageUrl = a + obj.src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the navigator.location.origin property and concat the string in runtime. For example:

```
var maskedImageUrla = "";

    $.getJSON('test.json', function(json) {
        for (let layer of json.layers) {
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0) {
                for (let temp of layer.layers) {
                    if (temp.src) {
                       maskedImageUrla = navigator.location.origin + '/images/' + temp.src;
                    }
                    else if (temp.layers) {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src) maskedImageUrla = tl.src;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi, do you have any idea how to fetch if there are multiple images in json ? i tried this code : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/RdwXpZ , but its displaying only one image....

Comment: @vickeycolors Well, that's another question :). Please post a new question with an example of what you're trying to achieve. With just this snippet, there's no way to point you to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can change this

```
 if (tl.src) maskedImageUrla = tl.src;
```

to this

```
if(tl.src.includes('/')){
   maskedImageUrla = tl.src
} else {
   maskedImageUrla = `http://sitename.com/images/${tl.src}`
}
```

Comment: @vickeycolors you need to replace only the inner if. show me how you replaced in your code. the error is pretty clear you don't have t1 defined.

Comment: Also here i added your code, please check [link](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/test67.html)

Comment: @vickeycolors You should check the code before copying it from the internet. There is a typo in the code. Instead of using `tl`, u have copied `t1` from the answer above

Comment: @CerlinBoss sorry for that, now updated code, still got this error : https://prnt.sc/mponlx , but i found solution and i will post it now.....

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png';


var strCopy = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, str.length);
console.log(strCopy);
console.log('http://sitename.com/images/' + strCopy);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have 1000's of json file, so its not possible to keep the image name as `oneheart.png` in each json files.....

Comment: hi, do you have any idea how to fetch if there are multiple images in json ? i tried this code : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/RdwXpZ , but its displaying only one image....

Comment: @vickeycolors you have to loop on your json and then pass your value in these params.

Comment: @vickeycolors tell me about the exact pattern of you json or does it vary ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the prefix to `t1.src` , i added the prefix to `temp.src`, so it was not working..... Below solution worked for me

```
var maskedImageUrla = "";

    $.getJSON('test.json', function(json) {
        for (let layer of json.layers) {
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0) {
                for (let temp of layer.layers) {
                   if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers) {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src) maskedImageUrla = 'http://sitename.com/images/' + tl.src;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```